# Downgrade from java 7 to java 6 on a mac

Tags: macos, java-7, java-6

Can somebody tell me where to find a java jdk 6?

I need to downgrade from 7 because I have some problems with java-7 on my mac. I installed the jdk 7 from oracle.

There is support for mac but there is nothing for lower then jdk7.

Any idea?

Comment: Why did you use the ios tag, the question doesn't seems to be related to ios?

Comment: sorry for the iOS; osx is better

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Java Preferences" to set the older jdk 6 to be your default JDK. Use "spotlight" to find Java Preferences panel.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559?viewlocale=en_US